# WPF application black after locking windows and resume to desktop

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, multithreading

We have a small problem with our .net 4.0 wpf application. If the user locks his screen (windows) and a few seconds later unlock the screen (resume to the work), the application looks like this:

[image: Lock-Bug]

The user can not click on any control or do some thing. The curious thing is,
that it only appears if the user is on special tabs, where we use `BeginInvoke` 
and work a lot with threading. I could not find any thing about this bug, besides that `BeginInvoke` can create those problems.

I also could not find any thing in the windows logs.

**EDIT**

I use multimonitor, if my application is black, removing the monitor cable an reconnecting it, the application continues to work.

Comment: debug this issue in VS . press pause a few times and see what thread your hang on.

Comment: @BendEg If this were an unmanaged application (I have never seen something like this in managed environment), my educated guess would be that somebody have overwritten the Paint/OnPaint handler of the form. Can you move/resize the blank form? Can it be minimized or maximized?

Comment: @mg30rg yes, i can move the form, but on the form there is nothing clickable. Nobody has overwritten some Paint-Methods. After reconnect my monitor it continues to work, so the problem must be on another leven, i think... Thank you

Comment: @BendEg When you dis- and reconnect (one of) your monitor(s), the desktop receives a WM_REFRESH message and indicates WM_REFRESH on all its children, including your form. That is why I assumed one of the Paint events are overwritten. Do you have any tool which with you can send a WM_PAINT to your form? Could you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem only seems to appear when using the wpf DataGrid. Switching from thsi grid to Telerik-Grid solve the problem, but i could not figure out which part cause the problem.